# Check the first character of a string in a c macro

Tags: c, string, parameters, macros

I am looking to create a macro that checks to see if the first character of a string is a defined character, the macro will be passed some text and a character and I would like to check to see if the first character of the text is what is passed as the character. What is the cleanest way of going about this?

```
#define Check(Text, character) ((CHECK IF THE FIRST SPACE IS THE CHARACTER) ? True : False)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that in a macro? Just write a simple function that checks for the first character and acts appropriately.

Comment: @ThaMe90 - doing it during preprocessing means it does not have to be done at runtime. The code that performs the check at runtime is not needed or present, so it can't fail or be exploited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define Check(Text, character) ((charachetr == Text[0]) ? True : False )
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply way to do it :

```
#define check(s,c) (s[0]==c)
```

For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define check(s,c) (s[0]==c)

int main ( )
{
    char * x = "test";
    if check(x,'t')
        printf("ok\n");
}
```